# "Unable to download. Content not supported" when forcing download on Android device

Tags: php, android

I'm writing a website which give a APK download automatically when someone accesses the link "http://www.sample-link.com/download/downloadApp
This is my code on PHP site.

```
    $fileName = "./uploads/MyAPK.apk";                           
    header('Content-type: application/download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; fileName="' . basename($fileName) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    readfile($fileName);
```

**When I visit that link on PC, it works. When I do it on Android devices, the download can't be done. It's stuck in the download queue with error "Unable to download. Content not supported"**. I tried to restart the device but it doesn't work. How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `application/vnd.android.package-archive` as content type for apks.

Reference: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29)